# Output not correct in C

Tags: arrays, c

I created a program for encoding and decoding a text. I done this by creating two arrays one having alphabets and other having numbers so when I encode the compiler split the string into single character and find the index of that particular character in array and change that character to a number which is in the same index of other array. And  decoding also was in same way. In output,When I encode the text it's working but when it comes to decide it's not working I will share my code below anyone please tell where my mistake was

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int encode(char dec[], int enc[]);
int decode(int enc[], char dec[]);
int indx(char arr[], char x);

int main()
{
    int c;
    char dec[] = {'A', 'a', 'B', 'b', 'C', 'c', 'D', 'd', 'E', 'e', 'F', 'f', 'G', 'g', 'H', 'h', 'I', 'i', 'J', 'j', 'K', 'k', 'L', 'l', 'M', 'm', 'N', 'n', 'O', 'o', 'P', 'p', 'Q', 'q', 'R', 'r', 'S', 's', 'T', 't', 'U', 'u', 'V', 'v', 'W', 'w', 'X', 'x', 'Y', 'y', 'Z', 'z'};
    int enc[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52}; 
    
    while(1)
    {
        printf("1.Encode\n");
        printf("2.Decode\n");
        printf("3.Exit\n");
        printf("Enter your choice");
        scanf("%d", &c); 
        if(c==1)
        { 
            encode(dec, enc);
        }
        else if(c==2)
        {
            decode(enc, dec);
        }
        else if(c==3)
        {
            break;
        }
        else{
            printf("Invalid choice!");
        }
        
        
    }
    
    return 0;  
}
int indch(char arr[], char x)
{
int arrlen = 52;
int indx;

for(int i=0; i<arrlen; i++)
{
        if(arr[i] == x)
        {
                indx = i;
                break;
        } 
}
return indx;
}

int indin(int arr[], int x)
{
int arrlen = 52;
int indx;

for(int i=0; i<arrlen; i++)
{
        if(arr[i] == x)
        {
                indx = i;
                break;
        } 
}
return indx;
}

int encode(char dec[], int enc[])
{
    char txt[100];
    int arrlen;
    int ind;
    char a;
    int i = 0;
    printf("Enter the text to be encoded:");
    scanf("%s", txt); 
    arrlen = sizeof txt / sizeof txt[0]; 
    while(txt[i]!= '\0')
    {
        a = txt[i];
        ind = indch(dec , a);
        printf("%d ",enc[ind]);
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}

int decode(int enc[], char dec[])
{
    int txt[100];
    int arrlen=0;
    int ind;
    int a;
    printf("Enter the code to be decoded:");
    for(int j=0;j<100;j++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &txt[j]);
        if(txt[j]=='\n')
        {
            break;
        }
        arrlen++; 
    }
    

    for(int i=0; i<arrlen; i++)
    {
        a = txt[i];
        ind = indin(enc, a);
        printf("%d", dec[ind]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `txt[j]=='\n'` is bogus. You are reading integer values. You will _not_ read a whitespace character such as a newline into an integer when you use `scanf` with `%d` format specifier. Maybe read the entire line as a string with `fgets` and parse the values out with `sscanf`.

Comment: `printf("%d", dec[ind]);` This will print the numerical value of the decoded character. Use `%c` instead.  BTW: Your `end` array is rather redundant. For all members it contains `enc[i] == i+1`. There is no need to use an array for calculating `+1`

Answer (score 0):

- As commented, it is recommended to use `fgets` and `sscanf` to avoid
  unexpected behaviors.
- You can simplify the algorithm by introducing a map which associates
  ascii codes to numbers (and vice versa) instead of looping in the array
  for the character.
- As the functions `encode` and `decode` return no meaningful values,
  it will be better to declare them as `void`.

Would you please try the following:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void encode(int *a2n);
void decode(int *n2a);

int main()
{
    int i, c;
    char str[BUFSIZ];
    char dec[] = {'A', 'a', 'B', 'b', 'C', 'c', 'D', 'd', 'E', 'e', 'F', 'f', 'G', 'g', 'H', 'h', 'I', 'i', 'J', 'j', 'K', 'k', 'L', 'l', 'M', 'm', 'N', 'n', 'O', 'o', 'P', 'p', 'Q', 'q', 'R', 'r', 'S', 's', 'T', 't', 'U', 'u', 'V', 'v', 'W', 'w', 'X', 'x', 'Y', 'y', 'Z', 'z'};
    int enc[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52};
    int a2n[128], n2a[128];             // assuming the character set is within ascii range

    // generate maps to associate character to the code and vice versa
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof dec; i++) {
        a2n[(int)dec[i]] = enc[i];      // map ascii code to a number
        n2a[enc[i]] = (int)dec[i];      // map a number to ascii code
    }

    while(1) {
        printf("1.Encode\n");
        printf("2.Decode\n");
        printf("3.Exit\n");
        printf("Enter your choice: ");
        fgets(str, BUFSIZ, stdin);
        sscanf(str, "%d", &c);

        switch(c) {
            case 1:
                encode(a2n);
                break;
            case 2:
                decode(n2a);
                break;
            case 3:
                return 0;
            default:
                printf("Invalid choice\n");
        }
    }
}

// encode a string to numbers
void encode(int *a2n)
{
    char str[BUFSIZ];
    char *p;
    printf("Enter the text to be encoded: ");
    fgets(str, BUFSIZ, stdin);

    for (p = str; *p != '\r' && *p != '\n'; p++) {
        printf("%d ", a2n[(int)*p]);
    }

    putchar('\n');
}

// decode numbers to a string
void decode(int *n2a)
{
    char str[BUFSIZ];
    int i, n;
    char *p;

    printf("Enter the code to be decoded: ");
    fgets(str, BUFSIZ, stdin);

    for (p = str; sscanf(p, "%d%n", &i, &n) == 1; p += n) {
        // You can make it robust by checking i is between 1 and 52
        printf("%c", n2a[i]);
    }

    putchar('\n');
}
```